# line trajectory in c

Tags: c

I am creating an engine.
Almost everything is working fine.
I can even do games with that.

I am doing a rpg game and decided to let
the dots to fire each other.
I already have a function to move the dots.
But this function in not linear.

So, that is the place I can't go on.
I need to change that function to make
those tragectories linear. So I can fire
a bullet or an arrow in the dots and that will
go straight to them.

This is the function I have now:

```c
PLACE_CALL STATUS PLACE_TYPE place_user_route(CHAINED * user, BP32 x, BP32 y) {
    if (user && USER_C(user->it)->object && bit_is_on(USER_C(user->it)->object->status, OBJECT_VISIBLE)) {
        OBJECT_SET * U = USER_C(user->it)->object;
        if (U->x_route == x && U->y_route == y) {
            obj_where_stop_all(U);
            return (On);
        }
        //printf("xs %f ys %f\n",object->x_speed,object->y_speed);
        if (U->x_route == x) {
            if (U->y_route > y) {
                U->y_route += -U->y_speed;
                U->where_stop_but(U, NORTH);
                if (U->y_route < y) {
                    U->y_route = y;
                    U->where_stop(U);
                    return (On);
                }
            }
            if (U->y_route < y) {
                U->y_route += U->y_speed;
                U->where_stop_but(U, SOUTH);
                if (U->y_route > y) {
                    U->where_stop(U);
                    U->y_route = y;
                    return (On);
                }
            }
            return (Off);
        }
        if (U->y_route == y) {
            if (U->x_route > x) {
                U->x_route += -U->x_speed;
                U->where_stop_but(U, WEST);
                if (U->x_route < x) {
                    U->where_stop(U);
                    U->x_route = x;
                    return (On);
                }
            }
            if (U->x_route < x) {
                U->x_route += U->x_speed;
                U->where_stop_but(U, EAST);
                if (U->x_route > x) {
                    U->where_stop(U);
                    U->x_route = x;
                    return (On);
                }
            }

            return (Off);
        }
        if (U->x_route > x) {
            U->x_route += -U->x_speed;
            if (U->x_route < x)U->x_route = x;
            if (U->y_route > y) {
                U->y_route += -U->y_speed;
                U->where_stop_but_and(U, NORTH, WEST);
                if (U->y_route < y)U->y_route = y;
            }
            if (U->y_route < y) {
                U->where_stop_but_and(U, SOUTH, WEST);
                U->y_route += U->y_speed;
            }
        }
        if (U->x_route < x) {
            U->x_route += U->x_speed;
            if (U->x_route > x)U->x_route = x;
            if (U->y_route < y) {
                U->y_route += U->y_speed;
                U->where_stop_but_and(U, SOUTH, EAST);
                if (U->y_route > y)U->y_route = y;
            }
            if (U->y_route > y) {
                U->y_route += -U->y_speed;
                U->where_stop_but_and(U, NORTH, EAST);
                if (U->y_route < y)U->y_route = y;
            }
        }
    }
    return (Off);
}
```

what can I change for that code to behave like straight?

Here is a part of the game working:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuLi_lB6c4Y&feature=youtu.be

Here is a function that I made, but it is not totally straight;

```c
PLACE_CALL void straight_line(CHAINED * user, BP32 x, BP32 y) {
    if (user) {
        OBJECT_SET * U = USER_C(user->it)->object;
        BP32 x_distancy = (x > U->x_route) ? round(x - U->x_route) : round(U->x_route - x);
        BP32 y_distancy = (y > U->y_route) ? round(y - U->y_route) : round(U->y_route - y);
        if (x_distancy && y_distancy) {
            if (x_distancy != y_distancy) {
                //if (U->x_speed_old != U->x_speed)U->x_speed_old = U->x_speed;
                //if (U->y_speed_old != U->y_speed)U->y_speed_old = U->y_speed;
                U->x_speed = (x_distancy / y_distancy) * U->resistance;
                U->y_speed = (y_distancy / x_distancy) * U->resistance;
            } else {
                if (U->x_speed != U->y_speed) {
                    //if (U->x_speed_old != U->x_speed)U->x_speed_old = U->x_speed;
                    //if (U->y_speed_old != U->y_speed)U->y_speed_old = U->y_speed;
                    U->x_speed = (U->x_speed > U->y_speed) ? U->x_speed : U->y_speed;
                    U->y_speed = (U->y_speed > U->x_speed) ? U->y_speed : U->x_speed;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (!x_distancy && !y_distancy) {
                //U->x_speed = U->x_speed_old;
                //U->y_speed = U->y_speed_old;
                U->x_route = x;
                U->y_route = y;
            }
            if (x_distancy && !y_distancy) {
                U->x_speed = (x_distancy / (x_distancy * U->resistance));
                //U->y_speed = U->y_speed_old;
                U->y_route = y;
            }
            if (y_distancy && !x_distancy) {
                U->y_speed = (y_distancy / (y_distancy * U->resistance));
                //U->x_speed = U->x_speed_old;
                U->x_route = x;
            }
            if (U->x_speed < 1 && U->y_speed < 1) {
                //U->x_speed = U->x_speed_old;
                //U->y_speed = U->y_speed_old;
                U->x_route = x;
                U->y_route = y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C or C++? Take your pick.

Comment: I am coding in c language.

Comment: So you basically want a line drawing algorithm? Google that, you'll get more good material than can fit in  SO answer. Or take a shortcut and go here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: If you replace `USER_C(user->it)->object` by a local variable U, your code would be half in size and double in readability.

Comment: It is basically that. I saw bresenha once. But it requires a for or do loop in order to work. The engine has to update that in a different way as you can see through the code above. So I could not find a way to implement bresenha into my code. Do you know I way for me to do that?

Comment: I changed the variable in order to make it cleaner.

Comment: Put the insides of the loop in a function. Then call that function once per game frame, instead of from a separate loop. You need more state variables though.

Comment: If I put a loop the process won't stop until the loop ends. I already tried this. Then, when the loop finishes the dot already did his movement